# electron/angular app get access to videos in a folder.

Tags: angular, electron

I'm using this package [angular-electron](http://%20https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron)

which gives me access to 'fs' on the angular side.

I have this function to traverse the folder

```
fs.readdir(this.path, (err, items) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const file = this.path + '/' + items[i];
    console.log('Start: ' + file);

    this.nodes.push({

      source: file

    })


    fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
      console.log(file);
      console.log(stats['size']);
    });
    console.log(this.nodes)
  }
})
```

I get back the right file path to the videos, however, when I use it as the src for the video player, I get file not found.

maybe I'm missing something basic, but my intention is to iterate through the files in a folder in the userPath and return a list of the videos in there to use as the media for a video player.

Answer (score 1):

Electron uses Chromium to present your app. It's still just a browser - same limitations like it can't access the local file system directly.

You could set up Express to serve the files for Electron's browser, eg.:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();    
app.use('/', express.static(this.path)); 
app.listen(3003);
```

Now if you have a `pic.jpg` in `this.path`, you can do this on the Angular side:

```
<img [src]="'http://localhost:3003/pic.jpg'" />
```

I'm not entirely sure if this will cause a cors issue, but if it does, simply add cors middleware like: https://github.com/expressjs/cors